# Putting breaks within a shift

Tags: optaplanner

I am solving a problem that is close to the nurse rostering one from the examples. Besides the default shiftAssignment (planning entity) -> employee(planning variable) I  have small assignments within the shift that divide the shift in N equal parts. So a shiftAssignment is connected with N different smallAssignment planning entity instances that have a planning variable “skill” because part of the planning must be with which skill will the employee be assigned to the smallAssignment instances not having the option to be unassigned , there must be a skill or it will be a break.

So another thing that also needs to be planned are the breaks that can take the place of M different small assignments where M is between 1 and a number smaller than N. The break is not with a fixed starting time and length that’s why it needs to be planned.

What would be the best way to deal with this problem?

1. Creating a custom move that will set the value of the variable “skill” in the M different small assignment instances to a special value that is part of the valueRange .
2. Make the break fixed with creating N different shiftAssignment instances as there can be break possibilities one for each break possibility and not creating the connected smallAssignment instances that span the time that the break is.
3. Making the break placement at the end either as the last phase or a separate solver
4. Considering a different option